# How to bind multiple form data between model and view in nuxtjs or vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have three forms on the page with a dropdown list on each form. I was trying to bind the data between the view and model. When I select each category in the dropdown, it should bind to each category variable in the array. How to use v-model and assign each category before posting?

```
<Select
          v-model="selectedCategory”
          class="w-full"
          @change="setCategory"
        >
          <option />
          <option
            v-for="category in productsData”
            :key="category.id"
            :value="category.id"
          >
            {{ category.description }}
          </option>
 </Select>
<Select
          v-model="selectedCategory”
          class="w-full"
          @change="setCategory"
        >
          <option />
          <option
            v-for="category in productsData”
            :key="category.id"
            :value="category.id"
          >
            {{ category.description }}
          </option>
 </Select>
 <Select
          v-model="selectedCategory”
          class="w-full"
          @change="setCategory"
        >
          <option />
          <option
            v-for="category in productsData”
            :key="category.id"
            :value="category.id"
          >
            {{ category.description }}
          </option>
 </Select>

 data(){
return {
selectedCategory: “”,
products: [
        {
          PROD_1_CATEGORY: '',
          VEND_1_OPTION_1: '',

        },
        {
          PROD_1_OPT_CATEGORY: '',
          VEND_1_OPT_OPTION_1: '',

        },
        {
          PROD_2_CATEGORY: '',
          VEND_2_OPTION_2: '',

        },
      ]
}
}
```

Comment: Put the correct reference into v-model

Comment: @Estradiaz, thanks.